# solana-py simulate transaction without signatures

Tags: signature, solana-py, simulate

i am using the solana-py lib and tried to simulate a given transaction that is not signed. Although the `simulate_transaction()` call has the argument `sig_verify` with the default being `False` already, i still get the Exception `AttributeError. transaction has not been signed correctly`. (`sig_verify=True` throws the same Exception).

[image]

Do you have an idea how to bypass the signature checks for a transaction simulation? Or why is the Exception still thrown with `sig_verify = False`?
I checked the implementation of the python adapter to the original RPC request and everything looks fine to me.

edit: especially because the documentation clearly states that a simulated transaction does not need to be signed: [image]

Comment: Where is your code for creating the transaction? Also, the default for sig_verify is false, so just remove that.

Comment: @BryonM the transaction object is a valid object, that (if signed correctly) also can be executed via the call `send_transaction()`, just the simulation fails if the transaction is not signed (per documentation the transaction doesn't need to be signed for a simulation though). Also obviously the default is false but the simulation still fails with `transaction has not been signed correctly`, which doesn't make any sense to me and is the whole reason i created this post.

Comment: Mind trying with the newest solana-py version?